# Calendar Month in Arabic

Tags: solspace-calendar

I am using the Month calendar. I would like to display the months and days in Arabic language. Can anyone help me with this?

---

Can you please guide me how to call the arabic calendar?

Answer (score 2):

For maximum control over the data and markup of a calendar, you should use the `{exp:calendar:cal}` tag instead of the `{exp:calendar:month}`. The latter is a shortcut to the former. Please see the **advanced** example in the documentation:
http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/month//#examples

You may also need to translate the language file in Calendar under `/system/expressionengine/third_party/calendar/language/english/lang.calendar.php`. Of course, instead of "english" you might want to create a separate "arabic" folder containing lang.calendar.php, to have `/system/expressionengine/third_party/calendar/language/arabic/lang.calendar.php`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I follwed the steps but I dont know how to call the arabic calendar. Can you please guide me how to call the arabic calendar?

Comment: The above enables you to *localize* Calendar (eg. display a Gregorian calendar in Arabic) and customize the markup. However, Calendar only supports the Gregorian calendar. Are you trying to create a non-Gregorian calendar? If so, this isn't supported by Calendar.

Comment: That's a good question, by "*the* Arabic calendar" @Seama may have been referring to Muslims' Hijri calendar. Interesting.

Comment: I translated the Gregorian calendar in to Arabic. My website is bilingual. By default the english calendar is shown. I would like the Arabic Calendar to be displayed when the language is switched to Arabic